# Dpdk --> mlx5_net: Cannot register matcher" in DPDK 22.11

Tags: dpdk

When I running dpdk-testpmd in DPDK 22.11, it reports the error:
[When I running dpdk-testpmd in DPDK 22.11, it reports the error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbUbJ.png)

I install dpdk some times,but not work! Why does this error occur? How should I fix it? ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include your code and errors as text and not as images (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).